# Django data in tables not showing up

Tags: django

My tables in my django don't show up , the titles for the table do but the data itself does not. can someone tell me what is wrong with my code please. Thank you

dashboard.html

```
{%  extends 'accounts/main.html' %}

{% block content %}

{%  include 'accounts/status.html' %}

<br>



    <div class="col-md-16">
        <h5>LAST 5 ORDERS</h5>
        <hr>
        <div class="card card-body">
            <a class="btn btn-primary  btn-sm btn-block" href="">Create Order</a>
            <table class="table table-sm">
                <tr>
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th>Language</th>
                    <th>Rating</th>
                    <th>Type of Media</th>
                    <th>Genre</th>
                    <th>Review</th>
                    <th>Notes</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Update</th>
                    <th>Remove</th>
                </tr>

                {% for media in medias %}
                    <tr>
                         <td>{{media.title}}</td>
                         <td>{{media.language}}</td>
                         <td>{{media.rating}}</td>
                         <td>{{media.type_of_media}}</td>
                         <td>{{media.genre}}</td>
                         <td>{{media.review}}</td>
                         <td>{{media.notes}}</td>
                         <td>{{media.date}}</td>
                         <td><a href="">Update</a></td>
                         <td><a href="">Delete</a></td>

                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}
        
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

{% endblock %}
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models


class Media(models.Model):
    CATEGORY = (
            ('Movie', 'Movie'),
            ('Tv Show', 'Tv Show'),
            ('Drama', 'Drama'),
            ('Other', 'Other'),
            )
    NUMBER = (
            ('1', '1'),
            ('2', '2'),
            ('3', '3'),
            ('4', '4'),
            ('5', '5'),
            )
    GROUP = (
            ('Action', 'Action'),
            ('Anime', 'Anime'),
            ('Comedy', 'Comedy'),
            ('Crime', 'Crime'),
            ('Fantasy', 'Fantasy'),
            ('Horror', 'Horror'),
            ('Romance', 'Romance'),
            ('Other', 'Other'),
            )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    language = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    rating = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, choices=NUMBER)
    type_of_media = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, choices=CATEGORY)
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, choices=GROUP)
    review = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True)
    notes = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Status(models.Model):
    POSITION = (
            ('Completed', 'Completed'),
            ('Continue Watching', 'Continue Watching'),
            ('Plan to Watch', 'Plan to Watch'),
            ('Dropped', 'Dropped'),
            )

    media = models.ForeignKey(Media, null=True,on_delete= models.SET_NULL)
    status_of_media = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, choices=POSITION)
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

from .models import *

# Create your views here.

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'accounts/dashboard.html')
    medias = Media.objects.all()

    context = {'medias': medias}

    return render(request, 'accounts/dashboard.html', context)

def products(request):
    return render(request, 'accounts/products.html')

def customer(request):
    return render(request, 'accounts/customer.html')
```

Those are all the relevant windows
Thanks

ignore this please i need more words to publish my question

def home(request):
return render(request, 'accounts/dashboard.html')
medias = Media.objects.all()

```
context = {'medias': medias}

return render(request, 'accounts/dashboard.html', context)
```

def products(request):
return render(request, 'accounts/products.html')

def customer(request):
return render(request, 'accounts/customer.html')

Comment: It might be already aware to you, but still you can refer the link to how to debug code to get more knowledge https://blog.hartleybrody.com/debugging-code-beginner/

Answer (score 0):

instead of this line.

```
{% for media in mediass %}
```

use the line below

```
{% for media in medias %}
```

you passed medias in your context.

I think you just misspelled  it

Comment: Hi, Thank you , i fixed that mistake but it still isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning before you add 'medias' to the context:

```
def home(request):
    **return render(request, 'accounts/dashboard.html')**
    medias = Media.objects.all()

    context = {'medias': medias}

    return render(request, 'accounts/dashboard.html', context)
```